# Confused as to how components are powered

Tags: electronics, theory

I have a fair knowledge of cars but one thing I cannot understand is how the components such as the radio/wipers/bulbs/heaters etc are connected to a power source ?

Let's say in your house you have a TV connected to the wall socket, the power comes from here. But in a car, how does the power physically connect to each component from the battery ?
Thanks

Comment: There are likely several 12V fuse boxes in your car, and wires running from those to everything. You just don't see the wires unless you open up panels and such (or add additional things that need power).

Comment: Ok thank you. So the battery connects to the fuseboxes, then to the components from there ?

Comment: Yes indeed - open your hood and trace the big fat wires from your battery. Compare where they go with information in the owner's manual on where the fuse box(es) is(are). Note that the alternator wiring is also going to the battery to keep it charged.

Comment: Here is a picture of a [wiring harness](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Choosak-Pornsing/publication/305411123/figure/fig1/AS:385561283055620@1468936381607/Automotive-Wiring-Harness-source-wwwswscojp.png). It is fitted to the car at an early stage of manufacture, so it ends up out of sight behind panels.

Comment: The "weird" thing about cars (and boats, and airplanes) is the metal frame is used as a negative return. Thus, consumers may have a return wire that runs to the frame, which the battery is also connected to. In some cases like starter motors, alternators and spark plugs, the return current flows through the device's external metal casing with no wire at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you think about it, the electricity is available at the wall socket, but technically, the power doesn't come from there. It is *routed* to the wall socket via wiring. A vehicle is no different. Power is provided by wiring, which is strung throughout the vehicle. **This is called a wiring harness**. As Jon Custer stated in comments, a fuse panel is in there some place to provide an interrupt in case too much power is drawn through any given circuit. Fuses are analogous to circuit breakers in the home. Without them, the wires can get hot enough to catch fire and cause all kinds of issues if too much power (amperage) is drawn through them.